# Receive and send mails from own domain via Gmail?

Tags: email, gmail, domain

I have an own domain example.com. Currently I receive mails through admin@example.com because my current host has the ability to forward all mails from admin@example.com to mymail@gmail.com

I will move example.com soon and not install a mailserver at all. A contact form sends mails via mandrill to admin@example.com.

I want to be able to receive these mails in Googlemail (like I'm used to) and be able to respond to them using admin@example.com.

What's the easiest way to accomplish that? Just set the MX-record of example.com to one of Google's mailserver?

Comment: Google will be happy to do this.  It just costs money.

Comment: ok via Google Apps for Business but is there an alternative for free?

Comment: There use to be a solution.  Google discontinued it.  What you want to do costs money.  So either setup your own mailserver and forward the email or pay Google and point your MX records to Google.

Answer (score 1):

Just sending the MX records wouldn't do much. The mail servers *don't know* that they should accept mail for that domain, much less deliver that mail to some specific inbox – they need to be configured first.

Gmail on your own domain is called "[Google Apps](https://www.google.com/work/apps/business/)", which you can sign up for at [$5/month](https://www.google.com/work/apps/business/pricing.html) if you only need one user account. (There used to be a free option, bit it is no longer available.)

Answer (score 0):

Google allows you to send email from different addresses. This requires a mail server somewhere though. You can forward your work email to a Gmail account, and then send email from Gmail using your work account. You can read up more about this [here](https://support.google.com/mail/answer/22370?hl=en).

If you don't have a primary mail server, you can use Google Apps for Business. The [basic plan](https://www.google.com/work/apps/business/pricing.html) starts at $5 per month per user. It gives you access to 30 GB of storage for your Google Products.